# Electric dipole moment of two infinite charged lines

Tags: electrostatics, dipole

Two parallel infinite opposite charged lines (of uniform density $\lambda$) are placed at distance $L$ from each other. Need to calculate the electric dipole moment of this system.

How do you do such a calculation? do I need to sum the moment dipoles of infinite tiny charges?

Comment: Do you mean the _electric dipole moment_? Are the two lines oppositely charged?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't mention

Answer (score 1):

The dipole moment of an arbitrary charge density distribution $\rho(\mathbf r)$ is defined as
$$
\mathbf d = \int \mathbf r \, \rho(\mathbf r) \:\!\mathrm d\mathbf r,
$$
where $\rho(\mathbf r) \:\!\mathrm d\mathbf r$ needs to be understood as a singular measure (say, using suitable delta-function distributions) in the case of point, surface or line charges. For the example of a line charge parametrized by $\mathbf r(s)$ over some parameter $s\in (a,b)$ and with longitudinal charge density $\lambda(s)$, this reads
$$
\mathbf d = \int_a^b \mathbf r(s) \:\! \lambda(s) \:\!\mathrm ds.
$$
If you have two infinite straight line charges at separation $a$ with constant longitudinal charge density $\lambda$ and with orthogonal unit separation vector $\mathbf u$, then this calculation yields a constant dipole moment $\Delta \mathbf p = \lambda \:\!\Delta L \:\! a\mathbf u$ per stretch of length $\Delta L$ of the two wires. The total dipole moment of the system can be inferred from that.

Comment: For "infinite" wire like the OP said, that would be like infinite dipole moment is it?

Comment: but Δp=λΔLau means p diverges for infinite wires, isn't it?

Comment: @Frogfire This answer has some intentional gaps that are there for you to figure out yourself. I hope this was clear from the get-go. If you find that conclusion shocking, then what expectations did you have that led you to expect a different result?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Well getting infinities always used to mean in our old literature as to something has gone wrong! :) But ya, I am convinced of this answer anyways.

Comment: @KV18 I'm not sure what all the fuss is about. If you start with a plainly unphysical situation, why are people surprised that the results are unphysical?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Well yeah ... I personally did not think a lot about it being a realistic wire or not ... but then by merely asking, people do start to think for themselves as to what is or is not possible, and of course get the most important thing out of all - clarity.